# How to loop through and compare millions of values in two text files?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, data-structures, loops

I have two text files files (TXT) which contain over 2 million distinct file names. I want to loop through all the names in the first file and find those that are also present in the second text file.

I have tried looping through the `StreamReader` but it takes a lot of time. I also tried the code below, but it still takes too much time.

```
StreamReader first = new StreamReader(path);
string strFirst = first.ReadToEnd();
string[] strarrFirst = strFirst.Split('\n');

 bool found = false;

StreamReader second = new StreamReader(path2);
string str = second.ReadToEnd();
string[] strarrSecond = str.Split('\n');

for (int j = 0; j < (strarrFirst.Length); j++)
{
          found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < (strarrSecond .Length); i++)
    {
        if (strarrFirst[j] == strarrSecond[i])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strarrFirst[j]);
    }
}
```

What is a good way to compare the files?

Comment: Your first mistake is reading the entire files as strings and splitting them.  You should have been making repeated calls to `ReadLine()` until you read in `null` (the typical, line reading loop).

Comment: @Jeff  - The TXT file size that I wanted to campare is over 300 MB, I tried using the ReadLine() but its taking much more time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
var commonNames = File.ReadLines(path).Intersect(File.ReadLines(path2));
```

That's O(N + M) instead of your current solution which tests *every* line in the first file with *every* line in the second file - O(N * M).

That's assuming you're using .NET 4. Otherwise, you could use `File.ReadAllLines`, but that will read the whole file into memory. Or you could write the equivalent of `File.ReadLines` yourself - it's not terribly hard.

Ultimately you're likely to be limited by file IO by the time you've got rid of the O(N * M) problem in your current code - there's not much way to get round that.

EDIT: For .NET 2, first let's implement something like `ReadLines`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we *really* want to use a `HashSet<T>`, but that wasn't in .NET 2 - so let's use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead:

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string line in ReadLines(path))
{
    map[line] = line;
}

List<string> intersection = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in ReadLines(path2))
{
    if (map.ContainsKey(line))
    {
        intersection.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but isn't it more correct to say that your solution is O(N) whereas his solution is O(N^2) ? ;-)

Comment: @CPX: There are two files involved - which size are you taking as N? That's why I've used N and M, one for each file.

Comment: @Jon I'm confused as to how Intersect or any other method of comparing 2 collections can be O(n+m). When reading an item in the second collection, does the whole first collection not need to searched for a match, thus making it O(n*m)

Comment: I think you should disregard the number of parameters and only look at the power of the parameters. N+M will increase linearly, thus O(N), while N*M will increase quadratically, thus O(N^2)

Comment: @CPX: But you may always know the size of the first file but with the second file size varying, or vice versa. There are clearly two variables here - I see no reason to combine them.

Comment: @saj: No - because `Intersect` reads the second sequence into a `HashSet` first, then looks up each item in the first sequence, which is an O(1) operation assuming a reasonable hash.

Comment: You can combine them if the files are of similar sizes (N≈M). Anyway, N² looks worse, so I prefer it `:)`

Comment: @All: Unfortunetly I am on .NET 2.0, can I still use the intersect menthod ?? I just wanted to avoid looping somehow, coz when the count of file increases, its taking minutes to compare.

Comment: @MayurJadhav: It would have been helpful if you'd said that before... I'll edit my answer. Obviously there's *got* to be looping somewhere, but you can avoid it being an O(N*M) problem.

Comment: @MayurJadhav: Okay, see my edited answer. That should have the same sort of runtime complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to speed it up a bit ...

```
            var path = string.Empty;
            var path2 = string.Empty;
            var strFirst = string.Empty;
            var str = string.Empty;
            var strarrFirst = new List<string>();
            var strarrSecond = new List<string>();

            using (var first = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                strFirst = first.ReadToEnd();
            }

            using (var second = new StreamReader(path2))
            {
                str = second.ReadToEnd();
            }


            strarrFirst.AddRange(strFirst.Split('\n'));

            strarrSecond.AddRange(str.Split('\n'));
            strarrSecond.Sort();

            foreach(var value in strarrFirst)
            {
                var found = strarrSecond.BinarySearch(value) >= 0;
                if (!found) Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
```

Comment: ReadToEnd is evil ... really should be reading line by line. Also make sure to use 'using' for streamreaders to ensure they are disposed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I've tried Jon Skeet method and own:

```
    var guidArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
        string path = "first.txt";
        File.WriteAllLines(path, guidArray);
        string path2 = "second.txt";
        File.WriteAllLines(path2, guidArray.Select(x=>DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks % 2 == 0 ? x : Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

        var start = DateTime.Now;

        var commonNames = File.ReadLines(path).Intersect(File.ReadLines(path2)).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);

        start = DateTime.Now;

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var hashset = new HashSet<string>(lines);

        var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(path2);

        var result = lines2.Where(hashset.Contains).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

And Skeet's method was tiny bit faster (1453.0831 vs 1488.0851, iDevForFun method was quite slow - 12791.7316), so i think under layers should happen same thing as I was trying to do manually with hashset.

Comment: That's interesting .. I would have thought a binary search would have helped performance quite a bit from the original code. Granted Jon's method is far more elegant and no doubt faster. That's what I love about this place ... learn something new every day :)